# JRebel removes all logging from a Grails project

Tags: java, grails, groovy, jrebel

I've got a project written in Grails. When I run it from a console with

```
grails run-app
```

I've got all my logs printed to the console, just as I want it.

However once I start it using JRebel, there are no logs visible anymore. Only some minimal set of information. JVM parameters are:

```
-javaagent:/path/to/my/jrebel.jar 
-Ddisable.auto.recompile=true 
-Drebel.spring_plugin=true
```

What could possibly be the cause of this? How do I get JRebel to print logs from my application (NOTE: this is not the same as JRebel logs - I'm not interested in what JRebel is doing, I'm interested in what my application is doing).

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what benefit do you gain using JRebel with Grails?

Comment: @Gregg Well, my experience is that Grails 1.3.7 mostly consists of bugs. In my case reloading kinda works, but not quite. Works for controllers and ... that's about it. JRebel works around this (however recently it failed me as well in a few cases). My project takes over a minute to launch, so I'm rather desperate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade to 2.0. It's at M2 now and will be at RC soon, with a release in November. All classes are now reloadable in development including Groovy classes, and the reloading is smart enough to rebuild your database when a domain class changes. So there won't be a need for JRebel.

Comment: I'll have a look in November then.